# Tizen Studio with .Net C#

Tags: c#, logging, tizen

How I can make a App using Tizen studio to implement .Net,C# Code?

I have web application with admin dashboard and user dashboard and I want to implement on Tizen app
How I can create Tizen app with created a log file send to admin dashboard? which backend language used in Tizen studio?

I have web application with admin dashboard and user dashboard and I want to implement on Tizen app
How I can create Tizen app with created a log file send to admin dashboard? which backend language used in Tizen studio?

Comment: For the first quesiton, Tizen support C / Web application development model by Tizen Studio, and, Tizen .NET is supported by Visual Studio or Visual Studio code.